# Disable one drive in mysite

Tags: 2016, mysite, onedrive

Is it possible to use mysite in SharePoint 2016 without OneDrive?

Is there away to disable it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

.............

Comment: Oh no, any workaround?

Comment: @Fabio I would hazard a guess that 99% of the use of MySite is a storage location for OneDrive.